# How to create horizontal grid

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am rendering bunch of `Input` components and I would like to display them horizontally side by side using some sort of Grid from `material-ui`.

Right now the components are rendering like this:

[image]

And I would like to render them like this:

[image]

So far I have tried this `Grid`:

```
<div style={{ row: 'horizontal' }}>
      <Grid item xs={4}>
            <Grid container justify="center" spacing={24}>
                  <Grid key={index} item>
                        <GalleryInput label="image" source={`${source}[${index}].image`} />
                        <br></br>
                        <TextInput label="desc" source={`${source}[${index}].desc`} />
                        {editable && <ButtonHelper icon={<RemoveIcon />} onClick={handleRemove(index)} className={classes.right} />}
                    </Grid>
             </Grid>
       </Grid>
</div>
```

But with no luck. Any suggestions how can I achieve this?
Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Add direction = "row"

```
<Grid container justify="center"  direction="row" spacing={24}>
```

refer to the material-ui documentation
[enter link description here](https://material-ui.com/components/grid/)

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not fix the issue for me.

Comment: add this in the parent Grid not the child

Answer (score -1):

you can do it simply with grid and padding/margin.

Check my example on codesandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-matsumoto-w83fc?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Also the documentation on material-ui is very helpful:

https://material-ui.com/components/grid/#spacing

hope this helps.